# Why does the last object get copied multiple times in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add objects of a *class* named *City* to an `ArrayList`. This is the code for the class

```
public class City {

    public static int x;
    public static int y;

    City(){
        Random rand = new Random();
        this.x = rand.nextInt(100)+1;
        this.y = rand.nextInt(100)+1;
    }
}
```

And this is the code of my *Main class*

```
    public static int N = 10;
    public static ArrayList<City> cities = new ArrayList<City>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        for (int i=1; i<N; i++){            
            cities.add(new City());
        }       

        for (City c : cities)
            System.out.print("("+c.x+", "+c.y+")");
    }

}
```

The result of `println` is always the same and it seems like the *array list* stores only the last object added in all of its elements.

For example the results I get when I run the program is:

```
(52, 93)(52, 93)(52, 93)(52, 93)(52, 93)(52, 93)(52, 93)(52, 93)(52, 93)
```

Why do I get that results? How can I it be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `x` and `y` variables in `City` are marked as `static`. A `static` member is shared across all instances of a `class` and is therefore a global variable. There are a couple of changes you need to make to your code :

1. Change the declaration of `x` and `y` variables in city to `private int x` and `private int y`. Ideally, fields of a class should not be `public`. See [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables) answer for a detailed explanation.
2. Add a `getX` and and `getY` method in the `City` class.
3. In the `main` method, access `x` and `y` using `getX` and `getY`.

Answer (score 13):

You should change the members of your `City` class to be non static:

```
public int x;
public int y;
```

static members are shared among all instances of a class, so all the instances would have the same values.

Comment: @Thomas yes, it would be better to make x and y private and access them via setter and getter methods.